# How to find Google Alert feed url?

Tags: php, rss, google-api, google-alerts

How can I find Google Alert feed url for specific keyword?

**Example URL:** http://www.google.com/reader/view/?hl=tr#stream/user/13172112245289928208/state/com.google/alerts/10573968695315493577

Number in red box indicates user id and number inside yellow box indicates feed url.

> How can I generate this url? Is there algorithm for generating these
>   numbers?

Maybe these numbers generated randomly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have created a google alert and you are getting this url in the reader part.The red integer symbolizes the user id and the yellow one tells the unique alert id.

There are two ways how you can get this url.This url is actually an rss feed .The actual feed url will be-

http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/userid/alertid

in your case it will be-

http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/13172112245289928208/10573968695315493577

This points to your user query son dakika.

For now you can use regex to get these numbers and then append them in the url www.google.com/alerts/feeds/to create the correct feeds.

Regards,
Vibhor Jaiswal